# payrequest adaptive payment ios through paypal

Tags: ios, paypal, sdk, p2p

I have built an app where I integrated paypal sdk and the concept is to make payment between users for the services they offer and opt. The mobile app does not wants to keep any money between. In paypal website it says it can be done through "PAYREQUEST" object and you can specify the complete information of receiver in this object. But unfortunately I am unable to make any such object. can anyone please help me. I am using Swift 2.0 and xcode 7.2
Thanks in advance

Comment: r u want adaptive payment in ios app?

Comment: I want p2p payment. Transaction just between user to user. No commission of the app in between. Thanks